# How to slice video in remote http server using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, centos, ffmpeg, amazon-ec2

I  want to  slice video from remote host .
i am using following command to do this

```
ffmpeg -i https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/video/messi.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

this working in windows without any issue . my ffmpeg version in windows is

```
C:\app\console>ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe
built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
```

when try same command from aws cent os. it not working 
getting following error

```
[tcp @ 0xa874b00] Failed to resolve hostname s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known
http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/video/messi.mp4: Input/output error
```

my  ffmpeg version in server is

```
ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg version 2.6.1-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-
```

How can i fix this ? i can download video using curl command

Comment: Your DNS resolution fails.

Comment: how can i fix ? but curl command is working.

Comment: can i pipe curl to ffmpeg ?

Comment: Yeah you should be able to pipe curl as it outputs to stdout by default. Check ffmpeg's documentation to see how to make it accept data on stdin.

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from each `ffmpeg` command.